# AngularJS UR-Router Reloads/Changes/Reverts to Previous State & Param and Calls Parent Twice/Multiple

Tags: angularjs, controller, state, reload, angular-ui-router

I am currently having a navigation issue with `ui-router`. Please see the code below in order for me to adequately describe the issue:

```
// routeMap.js

...

.state('instance', {
    url: '/{instanceId}',
    templateUrl: '/Public/tmpl/index.html',
    controller: controllers.InstanceController
})
.state('instance.case', {
    url: '/case',
    templateUrl: '/Public/tmpl/views/case/case.html',
    controller: controllers.CaseController,
    data: {
        param1: 'p1'
    },
    onEnter: transitionEvents.enter,
    onExit: transitionEvents.exit
})
.state('instance.case.incident', {
    url: '/incident',
    templateUrl: '/Public/tmpl/views/case/partials/incident.html',
    controller: controllers.CaseIncidentController
})

...
            
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('', '/')
    .otherwise('/error/404');

// instance.js

function instanceController($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location, DTO) {
    $scope.instanceId = $stateParams.instanceId;

    $rootScope.$emit('instanceId', { instanceId: $scope.instanceId });

    console.log('@state | #instance', $stateParams, $scope, $state);

    $state.go('instance.case', $stateParams);
}


// case.js

function caseController($scope, $state, $stateParams, $location, DTO) {
    //var persisted = DTO.serialize(true)
    //    , options = angular.extend(options, persisted);

    // Inherit from CaseDataModel to $scope
    CaseDataModel.call($scope, options);
    DTO.observe($scope);

    console.log('@state | #hotline', $stateParams);

    $scope.networkUserId = 'SomeUserId';
    $scope.callDate = moment();

    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.networkUserId = 'Brad Pitt';
        $scope.$apply();
    }, (1000 * 5));

    $state.go('instance.case.incident', $stateParams);
}
```

(The `incidentController` does nothing whatsoever in regards to routing)

### Desired Behavior:

I want to use the `'instance'` state merely for managing a global state based upon a case Id (`instanceId`) -- transition from `instance` to `instance.case`, and transition from there (once the case-controller has been called) to a child-state (`instance.case.incident`) -- AND -- be able to navigate from, say, `/new/case/incident` to `/998/case/incident`, and retain all correct state according to the `instanceId`.

### The Issue:

When navigating from `/new/case/incident` to `/998/case/incident` (and vice versa), the `'instance'` state loads and transitions to `'case'` -- passing the correct `instanceId` parameter -- (so far, so good...), the `'case'` state transitions to the `'incident'` state -- continuing the chain of passing on the correct `instanceId` parameter -- (yes... yes...), the `'incident'` state loads (bravo!... Magnifico!...) -- **then**, this process recurs, however, passing the *old `instanceId` parameter* of *new* -- running each controller, `onEnter` / `onExit` etc... (hogwash).

#### However:

When navigating from `/new/case/incident` to `/998/case` (and vice versa) -- WITHOUT the `'incident'` child-path -- the `'instance'` state transitions to the `'case'` state and the `'case'` state transitions to the `'incident'` state **without recursion of the process** of passing the *old/wrong* parameter back in -- this *is* desirable.

I have most definitely search (globally) for `ng-controller` and indeed only have one (`RootController`) function being referenced within the HTML.

Prethanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved this, but I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26941316/1148107), which was resolved by not using the optional curly brace parameter syntax.  As a test I moved the optional {parameter} around to different states and they all started to resolve twice. By adding onEnter and onExit and logging to the console you could see it: resolve, exit the previous state, load the current state, load the controller, resolve again, exit the current state, re-enter the current state, and load the controller again.  So it looks like we did the same thing.  At the very least I know not to use this syntax until there's a fix.  If you found an alternative solution I'd be interested to here it, I ended up using optional query parameters unfortunately.

**UPDATE**

This was issue in v0.2.11 and has apparently been solved in v0.2.12, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26958227/1148107)
Cheers