# ui-router state resolve entries are being evaluated twice when using an optional {parameter}

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

UI-Router resolve entries are reloading twice when using $state.go or ui-sref when using an optional {parameter}, and the optional parameter is not filled.

```
.state('dashboard.loan', {
    url: "/loan/:type/{instanceid}",
    templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/views/package.html',
    controller: 'PackageController',
    controllerAs: 'packageCtrl',
    resolve: {
        UserAuth: session
    }
})

// Resolves only once when both parameters are provided
$state.go( 'dashboard.loan',
           { packageType: packageType, 
             packageInstanceId: packageInstanceId } );


// Resolves twice when only one parameters is provided
$state.go( 'dashboard.loan',
           { packageType: packageType } );
```

I'm using ui-router v0.2.11.  Any ideas, can't seem to find a solution.

**Solution for v0.2.11**
Don't use optional curly brace query parameter

Comment: the way I would debug this is this: change the URL for `dashboard.index` to be similar to `dashboard.loan` and see if it makes `dashboard.index` load twice. If not then add similar `resolve` entries to `dashboard.index` one by one and see if this causes it to load twice. After that, if the cause is not determined, update the question and try to get more help.

Comment: also, I noticed that the `resolve` entries for `index.load` are inter-dependable. what happens if you remove `LoanPackage` from `LoanPackageInstance`?

Comment: besides, from your debug output it cannot be concluded that it is the state that is loading twice but that the resolved entries are being evaluated twice.

Comment: Hi @akonsu, if I remove LoanPackage from LoanPackageInstance I can't run LoanPackageInstance, since it won't be guaranteed to be resolved.  I have tried putting the LoanPackageInstance into the promise.success of LoanPackage, but comes up with the same results.  I'm trying to parallel dashboard.loan as another state right now.  I'll report back in a bit, hopefully with good news.  How would you look or test for resolved entries being evaluated twice?

Comment: Hi @akonsu, it appears that dropping both the resolves in dashboard.loan into another state doesn't make it load twice... so I'll try to reword my question, but I don't know really how to describe this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in 0.2.11 and should be fixed in 0.2.12.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1396

Comment: Chris you're a champ!  Cheers